# Content Provider generator for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, intellij-plugin

Do you know a Android Studio plugin for generate a Content Provider?

Recently, I switched from Eclipse to Android Studio, and I always used to use [mdsd plugin](https://code.google.com/p/mdsd-android-content-provider/) a plugin to generate a Content Provider from your domain model. I was wondering if there is any similar tool available for Android Studio.

I've found a couple of [tools](https://github.com/foxykeep/ContentProviderCodeGenerator) but you have to pass a JSON schema, and I prefer to use my model data definition instead of json.

Thanks!

Comment: `mdsd plugin` seems to be quite old without any updates/new versions, is it still up to that with decent code?

Comment: i tried the mdsd plugin, its easy to use, generates decent code, but it don't seem to support joined table queries, so this is why I'm not recommending it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found [Android ContentProvider Generator](https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator), it generates a ContentProvider and all database files given a several json files. It's pretty easy to use, but I would rather prefer the files structure that mdsd plugin generates. In any case this is the best option that I found.

Comment: I second this, I've used the [linked](https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator) content provider generator on several projects. It works well and cuts out a ton of boilerplate that usually puts people off  content providers.

Comment: A drawback of the generator mentioned above is the json format that is used to define the datamodel. A modern alternative is the [android code generator](http://uc-mobileapps.com/android-code-generator/) based on annotations. They also have sqlite schema creation with versioning and it seems to be free for open source projects.